# How do I raise a number to a power in Crystal Reports' Crystal Syntax?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'd like to do power a number to a another number in Crystal Syntax. There is any way to do something like this:

```
 pow({table.quantity}, {table.random})?
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

use the "^" operator:

```
{table.quantity} ^ {table.random}
```